# K&R - Understanding exercise 2-8: Exactly what is asked here?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I'm working through the exercises in the K&R book. Currently I'm stuck at exercise 2-8, which is says the following:

`Write a function rightrot(x, n) that returns the value of the integer x rotated to the right by n bit positions.`

The trouble I have is that I cannot seem to picture what the result SHOULD look like.

How or what do I rotate? Do I take the leftmost bit and put it to the rightmost position of `x`, after `x` is shifted to the left and repeat this for `n` bits? Or do I take a chunk (`n` bits) and put it `n` bits to the right while leaving the rest of the rightmost bits unchanged?

Any helpful answer is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can do both:) That can be a good exercise.

Comment: Yes well, I think so, too. But in this case I want to understand the exact implication of this exercise.

Comment: Do all options. It is an exercise after all :) I think the wanted behaviour is to make the binary digits less significant and move the least significant ones to the most significant positions: with 8 bit unsigned integers `"00000011"` rotated 2 would become `"11000000"`. Beware of the sign bit!

Comment: I didn't start with K&R, and On my entire life I did this with a preprocessor macro and some bitwise operations. Then when I first bought my original book and saw this exercise, I keep wondering if a function is really needed in this case.

Comment: I'm going by the book for learning purposes ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rotating means you're essentially shifting to the left or right but the bits otherwise "lost" will reappear on the other side.

It's a lot easier to explain with a decimal number:

Rotate `123456789` to the right by 3 digits will result in `789123456`.
Rotate `123456789` to the left by 4 digits will result in `567891234`.

So you'll essentially take n bits from one side and attach them to the others. It's a lot easier to understand if you think of all digits sitting on a circle or wheel you're rotating around the center.

To avoid confusin just replace "rotate" with "move" or "shift" and don't forget to save the bits otherwise lost.

Comment: A bit late, but thanks for the idea. I managed to implement a version in the spirit of your answer. Unfortunately, I can't post it here as I'm missing the source (hard drive went limb, waiting for the fix).

Answer (score 2):

Right idea but the other way.

Get rightmost bit. Shift right. Set the leftmost bit. Do this n times.

Comment: Can optimise by using n mod word length.

Comment: So it's essentially a swap of `n`-sized bit-chunks between both sides? @Quention: You mean `sizeof`()?

Comment: sizeof gets the number of bytes, what is wanted is the number of bits. But not needed you can or with (~0^(~0>>1)

Comment: For what it's worth, thank you for the hint! Managed to implement some sort of working function with this idea behind it.